# Determine HTTP method type

Tags: erlang, nitrogen

I'm trying to determine the HTTP method (GET, POST) send to an erlang module in nitrogen. I've added nitrogen as a dependency via rebar.

I'm attempting to do this via the [wf_context:request_method/0](https://github.com/nitrogen/nitrogen_core/blob/master/src/lib/wf_context.erl#L162) from nitrogen_core. However I can't figure out how to import/include the method. I've tried using [import/2](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/modules.html), include and include_lib. None have worked. Simply invoking the method with `wf_context:request_method()` doesn't work aswell.

The error I keep getting:

> {error,error,undef,[{wf_context,request_method,[],[]}, ...]}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding Nitrogen as a dependency requires a few more steps than just adding the base `nitrogen` application as a dependency, since each request requires a setup and teardown, and the Nitrogen server need to be started.

The simplest way to add Nitrogen to an existing application is to use the provided `embed` script.

You would do this as follows:

1. Make a temporary directory and clone nitrogen into it:

   `$ cd /tmp
   $ git clone git://github.com/nitrogen/nitrogen`
2. Change to your project's directory, and invoke the `embed` script

`$ cd /path/to/my/project
$ /tmp/nitrogen/embed`

Follow the directions on the prompt.  Unless you have a reason otherwise, the defaults are usually just fine.

I have a blog post I wrote about this a while back: http://sigma-star.com/blog/post/embedding-nitrogen

Once you've properly added nitrogen to your application, and the nitrogen process is started, you should be good to go, you will no longer `undef` errors for Nitrogen standard functions.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I had everything configured correctly. The problem was that i was using v2.2.2. in which the desired method wasn't yet implemented. The confusion arose from the fact that i was looking at the code from the master branch in github. Updating to {branch, master} fixed the problem. I'll accept your answer to "close" the question.

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks. Excellent! Version 2.3.0 will be released soon (one minor fix needs to be done then it's ready!), so having updated to master branch should not give you problems.